# Вылетает приложение андроид

Tags: json, java, android, pulltorefresh

Всем привет.

Пишу приложение, которое берет данные из `json` вывод в `ListView` - это работает. Нужно сделать еще `pull to refresh`. Добавил код, но почему-то приложение выбрасывает, а `LogCat` ничего не пишет. Вот код:

```
package avto.avtovesti_end;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class index extends TabGroupActivity {

    private static final String TAG_HREF = "href";

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ListView listview;
    HListAdapters adapter;
    ArrayList<homelist> homelist;
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    int current_page = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.index);

        final PullToRefresh listview = (PullToRefresh) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        homelist = new ArrayList<homelist>();

        new ListAsynTask().execute("http://auto.vesti.ru/utf/auto.json?type=homelist&offset=25");

        listview.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefresh.OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                listview.onRefreshComplete();
                            }

                        });
                    }

                }).start();
            }

        });

    /*    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String href = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.href)).getText().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), webviews.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_HREF, href);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });*/

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView lw, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    }

    public class ListAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(index.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Идет загрузка ... Ждемс...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "utf-8");

                    JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(data);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
                        homelist hmlist = new homelist();
                        JSONObject c = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);

                        hmlist.setTitle(c.getString("title"));
                        hmlist.setPictures(c.getString("picture"));
                        hmlist.setHref(c.getString("href"));
                        hmlist.setDate(c.getString("date"));
                        homelist.add(hmlist);

                    }

                    return true;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result == false){

            }else {

                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                adapter = new HListAdapters(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, homelist);
               listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

И еще, если кто-то знает, как сделать `load more`, буду безмерно благодарен.

Comment: Не очень понятно, как вы доступ к списку, адаптеру и прогресс-диалогу в асинк-таске получаете.

Comment: Простите, я новичок в андроиде. Можно вопрос, как для новичков. )))

Comment: @Alerx, стектрейс покажите. Пока смущает вот эта строка:

    ArrayList<homelist> homelist;

> В языке Java принято использовать UpperCamelCase для наименования классов и lowerCamelCase — для наименования экземпляров классов и методов.

И то, что вы обращаетесь в другом потоке (`doInBackground`) к этой переменной:

    homelist.add(hmlist);

Comment: Не пойму, где я его использую в другом потоке?